# How/what to import to dbdiagram.io?

Tags: sql-server, diagram, azure-data-studio

Hey I'm pretty new to databases and I want to create a diagram of the db I'm using with dbdiagram.io so that I can't understand the relationships better. What sort of script/file am I supposed to use to import the schema from sql server? I'm currently using azure data studio to query the database. I would prefer not to have to write out all the tables by hand.

Answer (score 0):

[Based on the docs](https://dbdiagram.io/docs/dbml) and [the DBML language](https://www.dbml.org/docs/#table-definition), you need to generate a DBML script in the following format from your RDBMS of choice - in this case, SQL Server:

```
Table Users {
  UserID integer [pk]
}

Table Posts {
  PostID integer [pk]
  UserID integer [ref: > Users.UserID] // many-to-one
}
```

Note that this DBML output is not intended to run on your RDBMS, SQL Server or otherwise - those platforms don't understand DBML. It is an example of output you need to generate *from* your RDBMS that you can paste directly into the left editor pane on dbdiagram.io, [as demonstrated here](https://dbdiagram.io/d/6332392f7b3d2034ffc0571d).

[This more complicated example](https://dbdiagram.io/d/6249d70fd043196e39e7d50b) - which uses DBML to build a diagram from SQL Server based on a subset of the tables in Stack Exchange Data Explorer (and which [I described here](https://sqlblog.org/2022/04/13/building-dbml-from-metadata)) - took about 40 seconds to create.

You can build this syntax from a set of tables without having to hard-code each one using catalog views like `sys.tables` and `sys.columns`, but there are a lot of little things that you'll have to do to make it compatible with this web site, and that will be a project all its own. Basically, nothing in SQL Server exists to generate nice, tidy DBML for you.

If you don't want to use DBML but would rather use the `Import` feature on the web site, then you can generate traditional DDL scripts instead - from SQL Server, you can do this by right-clicking the database in SSMS / Object Explorer and using `Script Database as` > `CREATE To`. Azure Data Studio doesn't yet have this functionality, but you can [use an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66578881/61305).

Comment: This answer is a bit rude and factually incorrect. If you attempt to import the script in Postgres exactly as written above, you get an error in dbdiagramio:

'Expected "ALTER","COMMENT","CREATE"....'

Comment: @Aaron-- which DBMS do these statement work for, then?